# Why do we have to wait to answer questions?

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange, meta

Why is there a 2 minute waiting period in between answering questions? I am posting here just because I started on the English learning exchange and don't have enough rep yet to post on their meta, but when some of the questions there can be answered so quickly, why does stack impose a waiting period?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Exchange, and to Personal Finance & Money in particular!

Users with a reputation of [less than 125 need to wait 3 minutes between posting answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/232449).  The reason for the rate limit is that they want to discourage new users from flooding a site with potentially poor answers, as well as slowing down spam posting attempts. Stack Exchange founder Jeff Atwood wrote a blog post [explaining the rationale behind rate limits](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rate-limiting-and-velocity-checking/).

I see that you have already posted several answers, which is great!  <strike>I'm sure you'll be above 125 in reputation before long, and this rate limit won't apply to you anymore.</strike> It looks like you've already passed 125 in rep, both here and on English Language Learners, so the rate limit shouldn't apply to you any longer.

I haven't reviewed any of your answers yet, but I just want to say that I doubt I've ever posted 2 answers in less than 3 minutes.  I usually spend more time on my answers than that.  While you are waiting for the waiting period to expire, you may want to take that time to review your own answer to try to improve it and make it the best it can be.